# CSV queryable by SQL

Tags: sql, csv

Is there a tool which would automatically provide me with a SQL interface on top of CSV files?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://harelba.github.io/q/

Example (from [their README](https://github.com/harelba/q/blob/master/README.markdown)):

```
q "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ./my_file.csv WHERE c3 > 32.3"
```

There is also a Python module & program: https://pythonhosted.org/querycsv/

Or in Go: https://github.com/dinedal/textql

You can also use this PowerShell script: [Invoke-CsvSqlcmd](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Query-CSV-with-SQL-c6c3c7e5)

Many other tools can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/7169/querying-a-csv-file).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://harelba.github.io/q/, you can execute the following command:

```
q"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ./clicks_file.csv WHERE c3 > 32.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's **External Table** feature.
You can use a local installation of Oracle -
**Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 ([Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html))**

---

This might require more work than other tools, but the data processing possibilities are endless.

---

```
create directory c_temp as 'c:\Temp';

create table myfile (c1 int,c2 int,c3 int) 
organization external (type oracle_loader default directory c_temp location ('myfile.csv'));

select * from myfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most powerful SQL OLAP tool to automatically query CSV files (and more) is [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/)

You can make some complex SQL request by ingesting CSV/TSV files with [automatic type/dialect recognition](https://duckdb.org/2023/10/27/csv-sniffer.html) and create in-memory tables even on small desktop computers

for instance

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table AS SELECT * from read_csv_auto('/tmp/sample_*.csv');
```

will import many CSV files in a single table detecting automatically the headers, separator and type for each columns so you can later run complex SQL queries

It runs on Windows/Linux/macOS from a single binary